# How to get finer discretization of 3D polytope?

Tags: regions, mesh, computational-geometry, polyhedra, discretization

For some purposes I need detailed mesh models of 2D and 3D shapes.  No problem with 2D, so for `Rectangle[]` we get for example

```
DiscretizeRegion[Rectangle[], 
   MaxCellMeasure -> {"Length" -> #}] & /@ {0.2, 0.1}
```

[image]
For `Sphere[]` it's OK too:
[image]
But for `Dodecahedron[]` result is undesirable:
[image]
*I need all the faces of dodecahedron to be disсretized detailed, just as rectangle above!*
I’ve tried every way: `MaxCellMeasure`, `BoundaryDiscretizeRegion`, `MeshRefinementFunction` etc, all the same ((

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Edit**

I found that `"Length" -> .2` work when we use `PolyhedronData["Dodecahedron", "BoundaryMeshRegion"]` instead of `Dodecahedron[]`. Of course, `PolyhedronData["Dodecahedron", "MeshRegion"]` still need to use `"Volume"`.

```
HighlightMesh[
 DiscretizeRegion[
  PolyhedronData["Dodecahedron", "BoundaryMeshRegion"], 
  MaxCellMeasure -> {"Length" -> .2}, AccuracyGoal -> 1], 1]
```

[image]

- Add the comment of @Syed

```
HighlightMesh[
   BoundaryDiscretizeRegion[Dodecahedron[], 
    MaxCellMeasure -> {"Length" -> #}], 1] & /@ {1, 1/2, 1/4, 1/8}
```

[image]

**Original**

Set `AccuracyGoal -> 5` and `"Volume"`.

```
HighlightMesh[
 DiscretizeRegion[Dodecahedron[], 
  MaxCellMeasure -> {"Volume" -> .002}, AccuracyGoal -> 5], 1]
```

[image]

Comment: Volume /)_-)   Many thanks!

Comment: I would hae used `DiscretizeRegion[Dodecahedron[], MaxCellMeasure -> {1 -> 0.05}]`. But surprisingly, it just ignores the edge length constraint `MaxCellMeasure ->{1 -> 0.05}`. Maybe it is worth reporting it as a bug?

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher, yes, anyway the need to use `Volume` keyword for facet mesh looks strange

Comment: I think you should really write Wolfram Support about this. They probably won't change this soon; but it is some feedback that they might appreciate.

Comment: `BoundaryDiscretizeRegion[Dodecahedron[], 
   MaxCellMeasure -> {2 -> #}] & /@ {1, 1/2, 1/4, 1/8}`

Comment: @Syed, aha, thank you! Docs for mesh regions should be improve =(